# Selenium : Automating LinkedIn - Profile Icon

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I am new to Selenium and trying to use Actions class to  mouseover on the Profile icon available on linked in site to open the menu that appears on Mouseover of profile image.

Below is my code and when it reaches on to those lines the error comes : **Unable to locate element..**

This is happening with all the icons available on Linked on top bar ( messages / Flag icon etc.

Code :

```
public class LinkedIn {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception { 

        String baseUrl = "http://www.linkedin.com/";    
        driver.get(baseUrl);

    }


    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login-email"));
        login.sendKeys("*****@gmail.com");

        WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("login-password"));
        pwd.sendKeys("*****");


        WebElement in = driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
        in.click();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }


     @Test
        public void profile()  {
    // here it gives error to me : Unable to locate element
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement profile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='img-defer-id-1-25469']"));
        action.moveToElement(profile).build().perform();
          driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have used incorrect xpath , Kindly check below example to mouse hover on Message button :

```
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            WebElement profile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='account-nav']/ul/li[1]"));
            action.moveToElement(profile).build().perform();
```

**Correct Xpaths are :**

For Message Icon : `"//*[@id='account-nav']/ul/li[1]"`

For Connection Icon : `//*[@id='dropdowntest']`

Above code I just tested and working fine so will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer and Connections and Messages did worked but i am still struggling for Profile icon please help ?

Comment: I am getting " Unable to find Element" Where as I have used correct Xpath: 
        WebElement profile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='img-defer-id-1-25469']"));